# How to use DropDown Node with Widget Container

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I'm trying to use the widget container from extension library - specifically I want to add a drop down node with options to run SSJS.

When using a basic leaf node in the widget container there are two options of interest.  "onClick" would appear to do exactly what I want.  However the code fires when the node is created - not just when it's clicked.  Actually it seems to fire all the time.

There's also submitValue.  I tried putting code in there as there's an example in the Ext. Library book on page 249 (SafariBooksOnline Version) but I couldn't get that code to run it seems.

```
<xe:this.dropDownNodes>
<xe:basicLeafNode label="New Category">
<xe:this.onClick><![CDATA[#{javascript:print("onClick Code")
}]]></xe:this.onClick>
<xe:this.submitValue><![CDATA[#{javascript:print("SubmitValue Code");
sessionScope.put("currentDoc", "");
viewScope.put("showSub", false)
var c = getComponent("dynamic")
c.show("cat")}]]></xe:this.submitValue>
</xe:basicLeafNode>
<xe:basicLeafNode label="Another option"></xe:basicLeafNode>
</xe:this.dropDownNodes>
```

What I'm looking to do is in this done call code to set scoped variables and then update a dynamic control on the page.  In theory I think I would need a partial refresh but I don't see a way to set that.

In the code example I gave - the onClick runs when things are not clicked and the submitValue - which has the code I'm interested in doesn't seem to fire at all.

Any advice would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Apparently inside of the ApplciationLayout Control the basicLeafNode's onclick method does not define a place to put an SSJS call, but in fact defines a place to run CSJS.  Also the submitValue is a place to put a value, so to get the behavior that you are seeking you should set the submitValue to something like "NewCategoryClick" and then define an eventHandler child under the applicationLayout that checks to see if the submittedValue == "NewCategoryClick" then run your SSJS code that you have defined.